# How to extract words from a tuple in python

Tags: python, regex, tuples

```
(0, u'0.559*"delivery" + 0.124*"area" + 0.018*"mile" + 0.016*"option" + 0.012*"partner" + 0.011*"traffic" + 0.011*"hub" + 0.011*"thanks" + 0.010*"city" + 0.009*"way"')
(1, u'0.397*"package" + 0.073*"address" + 0.055*"time" + 0.047*"customer" + 0.045*"apartment" + 0.037*"delivery" + 0.031*"number" + 0.026*"item" + 0.021*"support" + 0.018*"door"')
(2, u'0.190*"time" + 0.127*"order" + 0.113*"minute" + 0.075*"pickup" + 0.074*"restaurant" + 0.031*"food" + 0.027*"support" + 0.027*"delivery" + 0.026*"pick" + 0.018*"min"')
(3, u'0.072*"code" + 0.067*"gps" + 0.053*"map" + 0.050*"street" + 0.047*"building" + 0.043*"address" + 0.042*"navigation" + 0.039*"access" + 0.035*"point" + 0.028*"gate"')
```

How to extract top 3 words (based on the number along side) from each of the above tuples?

OUTPUT should be:

```
(0,delivery area mile)
(1,package address time)
(2,time order minute)
(3, code gps map)
```

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: please [edit] your question to show what you're expecting. This seems like a good potential question, but not like that. Answers may answer or not to your question...

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the output

Comment: @Arman, should those 3 words be a single string or a list?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest They should be a string

Comment: what if the "coefficients" are not in decreasing order? should we still take the 3 first ones in the list?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, then it should be the 3 words with the highest coefficients (we should sort them in decreasing order first?)

Comment: @Arman, it would be better if they go in random order in your tuples, because now, they are already start with highest 3 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- create tuples (coefficient,value) by splitting according to `" + "` (regex could be needed if the number of spaces vary), then according to `"*"`
- sort those tuples according to floating point value of the coefficient, keep the highest 3
- drop the coefficients and join the strings (stripping the quotes in the process)

In a (complex) one-liner:

```
l = [(0, u'0.124*"area" + 0.018*"mile" + 0.016*"option" + 0.012*"partner" + 0.011*"traffic" + 0.011*"hub" + 0.011*"thanks" + 0.559*"delivery" + 0.010*"city" + 0.009*"way"'),
(1, u'0.073*"address" + 0.055*"time" + 0.397*"package" + 0.047*"customer" + 0.045*"apartment" + 0.037*"delivery" + 0.031*"number" + 0.026*"item" + 0.021*"support" + 0.018*"door"'),
(2, u'0.190*"time" + 0.127*"order" + 0.113*"minute" + 0.075*"pickup" + 0.074*"restaurant" + 0.031*"food" + 0.027*"support" + 0.027*"delivery" + 0.026*"pick" + 0.018*"min"'),
(3, u'0.047*"building" + 0.072*"code" + 0.067*"gps" + 0.053*"map" + 0.050*"street" + 0.043*"address" + 0.042*"navigation" + 0.039*"access" + 0.035*"point" + 0.028*"gate"')]

result = [" ".join(x[1].strip('"') for x in sorted((e.split("*") for e in sl[1].split(" + ")),key=lambda x:float(x[0]),reverse=True)[:3]) for sl in l]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['delivery area mile', 'package address time', 'time order minute', 'code gps map']
```

(note that I have shuffled the order of the items to test the coeff sorting)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.findall()` and `str.join()` functions:

```
import re

l = [
(0, u'0.559*"delivery" + 0.124*"area" + 0.018*"mile" + 0.016*"option" + 0.012*"partner" + 0.011*"traffic" + 0.011*"hub" + 0.011*"thanks" + 0.010*"city" + 0.009*"way"'),
(1, u'0.397*"package" + 0.073*"address" + 0.055*"time" + 0.047*"customer" + 0.045*"apartment" + 0.037*"delivery" + 0.031*"number" + 0.026*"item" + 0.021*"support" + 0.018*"door"'),
(2, u'0.190*"time" + 0.127*"order" + 0.113*"minute" + 0.075*"pickup" + 0.074*"restaurant" + 0.031*"food" + 0.027*"support" + 0.027*"delivery" + 0.026*"pick" + 0.018*"min"'),
(3, u'0.072*"code" + 0.067*"gps" + 0.053*"map" + 0.050*"street" + 0.047*"building" + 0.043*"address" + 0.042*"navigation" + 0.039*"access" + 0.035*"point" + 0.028*"gate"')
]

result = [tuple([t[0], ' '.join(re.findall(r'"([a-z]+)"', t[1])[0:3])]) for t in l]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[(0, 'delivery area mile'), (1, 'package address time'), (2, 'time order minute'), (3, 'code gps map')]
```

Comment: that supposes that the coefficients are in the decreasing order. Else it doesn't work

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I also thought about sorted items at start, but it seems that the "first" 3 is intended